# Find $\sigma(T)$ and the norm of the operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $\{e_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$  is orthonormal basis. Suppose that $z = \{z_j\}_{j = 1}^{\infty} \in c_0$. Define the linear operator S from Hilbert space $H$ to $H$ as:

$$Sx = \Sigma_{m = 1}^{\infty} z_m (x,e_k)e_k$$

Find $\sigma(S)$ and $\|S\|$

I think that $\|S\|$ is $sup_{j \geq 1} |z_j| = \|z\|_{\infty}$. I did partial work, but I am having troubles with one of the inequalities.

$$sup_{k \geq 1} \|Se_k\| = sup_{k \geq 1} \|z_k e_k\| = sup_{k \geq 1} |z_k| \|e_k\| = \|z\|_{\infty}$$

Therefore we get the following inequality:

$$\|S\| \geq \|z\|_{\infty}$$

Conversely, given $x \in H$, consider the following:
$$\|Sx\| = lim_{N_1 \rightarrow \infty} lim_{N_2 \rightarrow \infty} (\Sigma_{i = 1}^{N_1}z_i (x,e_i)e_i,\Sigma_{j = 1}^{N_2}z_j (x,e_j)e_j) \leq \Sigma_{i = 1}^{\infty} |z_i|^2$$

The above inequality is true if we take $x \in H : \|x\| = 1$.
 Note in the above inequality we used Cauchy Schwarz, continuity of inner product, and orthonormality of the sequence.

But this doesn't tell us much about $\|z\|_{\infty}$. I also have no idea how to find $\sigma(S)$.

Comment: Why is it true that $\sqrt ( {\Sigma_i |z_i|^2 } )$ is finite though we don't know this.

Comment: To prove $\|S\| = \|z\|_\infty$, just note that $\|Sx\|^2 =  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \|z_i\|^2 \lvert (x,e_i) \rvert^2 \leq \|z\|_\infty^2 \|x\|^2$.
For $\sigma(T)$, it might help to think of $T$ as an infinite-dimensional matrix. This way it should be clear what (most of) the eigenvalues are.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $||S||=||z||_\infty$ and $\sigma (S)$ is the closure of $\{z_k:k\geq 1\}$. First note that $||Sx||^{2}=\sum_1^\infty |z_k|^{2} |<x,e_k>|^{2} \leq (||z||_\infty)^{2} \sum_1^\infty  |<x,e_k>|^{2}$ so $||Sx||^{2}\leq (||z||_\infty)^{2} ||x||^{2}$. This proves that $||SX||\leq ||z||_\infty$. Since $Se_k=z_k e_k$ we see that $||S|| \geq |z_k|$ for each k. Hence $||S|| \geq ||z||_\infty$. For the second part note that $Se_k=z_k e_k$ so each $z_k$ is in the spectrum. It follows that $\sigma (S)$ contains the closure of $\{z_k:k\geq 1\}$. Now suppose z is not in the closure of $\{z_k:k\geq 1\}$. Then there is a positive number r such that  $|z-z_k|>r$ for each k. In this case $(S-zI$ has an inverse: the inverse, $T$ is given  $Tx=\sum_1^\infty \frac 1 {z_k -z} <x,e_k>e_k$.